# Ruby gem organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use the same gem in different environments, but when I do:

```
gem 'pg' # To use in development.

group :production do
  gem 'pg' # another mention.
  gem 'rails12_factor'
end
```

I get the `you've mentioned the same gem twice etc...` comment. What is the best way to organize this so that I can use the same gem in different environments? `group :assets` was dropped for rails 4. That seemed like a more intuitive way to do it. It has something to do with precompilation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not specifying environment externally, it will be available in all the environments.

```
gem 'pg' # It will be available in all the environments

group :production do
 gem 'rails12_factor'
end
```

Comment: thanks @RAJ, so any gems that are not implicity stateted to be used in a given environment will be included in all environments. ie not like group :production do